# How to show 12 months at once in Angular UI-Calendar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm trying to implement a calendar in angular-ui calendar library. Is there a way i can show all 12 months of a year at once. so fare I've only managed to show one month at a time.

if this library doesn't provide this feature is there anything else i can use to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using that particular library, you would need to show twelve of them in a row.

You could then write a directive to simplify this process if you then wanted to reuse the 'year view' in other places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to some else options can check this link there is some example and edit this plugin you can get your result http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/